# An attempt to place a null value in a non-nullable datatype

Tags: testing, dbunit, ingres, unitils

I'm using dbunit and unitils trying to get test sensitive dates on my dataset files.

```
 public void setUp() {
String dataSetFile = "/Dataset.xml";
IDataSet dataSet;
try {
    dataSet = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new FileInputStream(dataSetFile));
    rDataSet = new ReplacementDataSet(dataSet);
    rDataSet.addReplacementObject("[var1]", TestDates.getDatasetDate(2));
    rDataSet.addReplacementObject("[var2]", DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), 3));
    rDataSet.addReplacementObject("[var3]", DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), 1));

    DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(getConnection(), rDataSet);


@Test....
```

The problem is when running this I get error

```
   An attempt to place a null value in a non-nullable datatype.
```

Dataset:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
 <table id="1720"
 var1="[var1]"
 var2="[var2]"
 somedate="2013-02-25 08:00:00"
 var3="[var3]"
   />
 </dataset>
```

What's the fix? Is it somewhere in date formating? Or database itself? Its Ingres.

Comment: Could you post your dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataset had missing column. In some techniques no column definition inserts empty to column in question, so it missled me.